# Powershell and entering data

Tags: powershell

I am trying to automate checking tenant names using the o365.rock website. I want to enter the tenant name and click the button. however I keep getting errors when trying to put the data in the field.

My test code is:-

```
$site = "https://o365.rocks"
Start-Process "chrome.exe" $site
while ($site.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 1;} 
$input = $site.Document.getElementByID("INPUT");
$input.value = "testing";
```

I keep getting this error

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:4 char:1
> $input = $site.Document.getElementByID("INPUT");

I have inspected the elements and the field only has a tagname of "INPUT". The name & ID fields are blank.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong or how else to do this?

Comment: as an aside - the `$Input` variable is one of the automatic variables that  PoSh uses. **_that $var will change its value whenever PoSh decides to change it._** for that reason, best practice is to NEVER use it unless you need to use it for the purpose it is designed for. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the field ID name because you are using

```
site.Document.getElementByID
```

which is looking at the ID part of the field.

Or better use

```
 $tag_name = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
```

Comment: See the comment by @Lee_Dailey about [$input being an Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the availability of an Office 365 tenant name using the following code:

```
$TenantName = "contoso"
$URI = "https://tenantchecker.easy365manager.com/api/CheckTenantName/" + $TenantName
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI -Method GET -ContentType 'application/json').Content | ConvertFrom-Json
```

(source info: https://www.easy365manager.com/tenant-availability-checker/)